# Push Notification Entitlement - Issue while uploading app to app store

Tags: ios, app-store

I get the following mail after submitting my app:

```
App Store Connect

Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "Zapit" 1.0.0 (1). Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:

ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the 'aps-environment' entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the 'aps-environment' entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

Best regards,

The App Store Team
```

I never enabled push notification, and it is not enable in https://developer.apple.com/

[image]

So have no idea how to work it out.

What does it mean `app signature's entitlements do not include the 'aps-environment' entitlement.`? and how to I include it?

Where can I disable Apple Push Notification service?

Will I prevent my app from being approve, or I can dimply ignore this?

**More info:**

I just saw that under `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles`/`Generate a Provisioning Profile` I had `Push Notification` under `Enabled Capabilities`

I deleted the `Generate a Provisioning Profile` and created a new one
[image]

I assume it was cause by choosing the first option here
[image]

So I tried to go with the second one, now im getting `Profile doesn't include the selected signing certificate.`

[image]

How do I include the selected signing certificate in the profile?

Comment: To include the certificate you have to create a new provision profile and select this certificate. You can not include certificate into an existing profile

Comment: Can you explain? I created a new profile, but I couldn't figure how to select the certificates

Comment: One of the steps of creating a new profile is picking a certificate. you can google for `how to create distribution certificate`. Here's the first result https://clearbridgemobile.com/how-to-create-a-distribution-provisioning-profile-for-ios/

Comment: @TiranUt I did that, of course, but I couldn't figure how to select the certificates, if you go through the link u suplied u can see there is no such option.

Comment: Any way, it seems that this error can be simply ignored, my app didn't pass the review yet!? but for other reason, the reviewer didn't address this issue.

Comment: There's no way to  create app store profile without selecting the certificate. I've just created a new appstore provision and I was suggested to pick the certificate http://joxi.ru/a2XXwDyUDjROL2.

Comment: The link I provided doesn't have a picture of the stage where you select the certificate but it is still mentioned. Read number 4 - http://joxi.ru/1A5o81eCG8g3Gm

Comment: So I guess I don't understand what a certificate is, but any way, I had only one option to choose from so I guess I chose the correct one, but the errors remains

Comment: Are there any other certificates except the default one in the manual sign menu? The problem you have can be either with the certificate or with provision.

Comment: Since you said you have only one certificate it looks like you haven't downloaded the provision, so you can try pressing info button to the right of provision dropdown list and select download profile. You will be suggested to download an appropriate one if it exists.